# PHP Show "You" Favorited this in the first of another User favorite

Tags: php

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT U.username, U.uid, U.full_name, M.uid_fk FROM tb_favorite M, tb_user U WHERE U.uid = M.uid_fk AND M.msg_id_fk = '$get_post_id' LIMIT 3");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $like_uid = $row['uid_fk'];
    $likeusername = $row['username'];
    $likefull_name = $row['full_name'];

if($like_uid == $uid)
{
    echo '<span id="youlikes'.$get_post_id.'">You</span>';
}
else
{
    echo '<span id="youlike'.$get_post_id.'"></span> <a href="'.$likeusername.'">'.$likefull_name.' </a>';
}
}
favorited this
```

Assuming I login using user1 (User1 is You).
When the query running, it will show like this :

```
You, user2, User3 favorited this.
```

But if I login using user2, when query running, it will show like this :

```
User1, You, User3 favorited this.
```

I think it's because the first saved to table will show first.

What I want is, when I log on using User1/User2/User3, "You" must be first of another user when favorited this.

Comment: stop using deprecated `mysql_*` function; use PDO / MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `order by`,

```
SELECT U.username, U.uid, U.full_name, M.uid_fk FROM tb_favorite M, tb_user U
WHERE U.uid = M.uid_fk AND M.msg_id_fk = '$get_post_id'
ORDER BY U.uid = $uid DESC
LIMIT 3
```

**Warning:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. I add single quote in $uid, ORDER BY U.uid = '$uid' DESC.

Comment: Glad to help you. Make sure you read the deprecated function warning too I have updated in my answer :)